# Distribute lines of code to workers

Tags: matlab, parallel-processing

Say I have the following code:

```
a = 5;
x = function1(a);
y = function2(a);
```

What I want to do is to assign the computation of function1 to one worker and the computation of function2 to another worker such that I can compute them in parallel. Each of the functions have to be computed in serial, so I cannot use spmd around the statement. Are there any other possibilities?

Comment: My first thought is to use parfor on a cell array of function handles, , fh = {@function1, @function2}, but I wonder if parfor will accept that?

Comment: If each of the functions have to be computed in serial, then you can't execute them in parallel. If you can't do it in an SPMD block in MATLAB then you can't do it in parallel in MATLAB.

Comment: So function1 have to be ran in serial, and function2 have to be ran in serial. But they do not depend on each other so the computation of function1 can be in parallel with function2. Is this also the question that you answered, Michael J?

Answer (score 1):

You could use [`parfeval`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/distcomp/parfeval.html) for this, like so:

```
a = 5;
xfut = parfeval(@function1, 1, a); % second arg is number of outputs from function1
yfut = parfeval(@function2, 1, a);
```

You can get the outputs of the functions using the method `fetchOutputs` on `xfut` and `yfut`. You can use the `wait` method to wait until one or both complete.